# BCP unable to open host data file when migrating to Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, bcp

I haver a sample GTFS data file I am attempting to load to Azure.  The command I am using is:

```
bcp %fullTablePath% in %data_dir% -f %format_file% -S %server% -U %username% -P %password% -k -F %first_row%
```

where the parameters are replaced accordingly.

When I execute the command, I get:

SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file

This is not a file naming issue because the file is indeed there.  If I deliberately spell the file incorrectly, I get the same error.  Sounds like a permission issue but who do I grant what permission?

Comment: What are the target file permissions for the user that you've logged in as?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek, I am assuming this is for the user on SQL Azure?  If so, is there a way to do this on Azure?

Comment: From the error, it appears as if there is a permissions problem with BCP because it is unable to open the specified file. From a similar question that was asked, can you please verify the following (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b4594df2-c9b5-4635-a7fc-4ec9c9f2a061/unable-to-open-bcp-host-datafile-error)

1. The account being used to run BCP does have rights to write to the target folder.
2. The path or filename is correct.
3. The file is NOT already opened by something else.

Comment: I am logged into my laptop as admin.  BCP is being executed directly from PowerShell. My logged in user has read/write permissions to the folder containing the data file.  I put them there!   Import is being done to Azure so SQLServer security context may not apply here.  Do not know.

Comment: Some missing context. This error occurs only when I execute bcp from a batch file.  If I bcp directly from PowerShell, I do not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error in batch file but not from PowerShell check that your
%fullTablePath% or %data_dir% variables are full qualify path/absolute path and not relative path as PowerShell and Batch may have different default path settings which may give you the error of:

Unable to open BCP host data-file

Comment: I am printing the variables %fullTablePath% and %data_dir% and they are absolute paths.  I am suspecting this has to do with BCP not having read permissions to these directories.  I am having another permission issue with a Python script reading files from same directory.  Directory is c:\dev\tut\data\oc_transpo.  Have not tried but I suspect placing files in c:\users\knji\documents will work.

Comment: Can you please share the code (removing any personal information that is not necessary)?